# AWS EMR, Submit python pyspark script as step using terraform

Tags: pyspark, terraform, amazon-emr

I have successfully created an EMR cluster using terraform, as per terraform documentation, it's specified on how to submit a step to EMR as a jar
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/emr_cluster.html#step-1

```
step {
    action_on_failure = "TERMINATE_CLUSTER"
    name              = "Setup Hadoop Debugging"

    hadoop_jar_step {
      jar  = "command-runner.jar"
      args = ["state-pusher-script"]
    }
  }
```

where as documentation for adding a pyspark script as a step is missing.
Does anyone has experience adding pyspark script as EMR step using terraform ?

Answer (score 0):

A common way to do this is to copy a script from S3 and use `command-runner.jar` to execute the script. (I don't know that it's ideal...)

```
  step = [
    {
      name              = "Copy script"
      action_on_failure = "CONTINUE"

      hadoop_jar_step {
        jar  = "command-runner.jar"
        args = ["aws", "s3", "cp", "s3://path/to/script.py", "/home/hadoop/"]
      }
    },
    {
      name              = "Run script"
      action_on_failure = "CONTINUE"

      hadoop_jar_step {
        jar  = "command-runner.jar"
        args = ["bash", "/home/hadoop/script.py"]
      }
    },
  ]
```

Comment: I get error like Inappropriate value for attribute "step": element 0: attribute
"hadoop_jar_step": element 0: attributes "main_class" and "properties" are required.

Comment: Yep, I just ran into this error myself.  The docs say the attributes are optional but the tool requires them.  I've opened an issue: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/20911

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of using `hadoop_jar_step`.

```
  step = [
    {
      action_on_failure = "TERMINATE_CLUSTER"
      name              = "Setup Hadoop Debugging"

      hadoop_jar_step = [
        {
          jar = "command-runner.jar"
          args = [
            "state-pusher-script"
          ]
          main_class = ""
          properties = {}
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Contains workaround for https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/20911

Change `args` to your `spark-submit` command.